# Running .sh file right after login and root login

Tags: command-line, 16.04, sh

How can I automatically run a .sh file right after I login with my regular credentials, and my root password. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou can do that with a `.desktop` file placed in `~/.config/autostart`. To create such a file simply do:

```
cat > ~/.config/autostart/myscript.desktop << "EOF"
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myscript.sh
GenericName=my script for foo-fu
Comment=does bar the foo or fu foos the bar
Exec=sh ~/scripts/myscript.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Script
Icon= 
Categories=Tools;
StartupNotify=true
EOF
```

Up to that make sure you have done a `chmod 755` on that script by:

```
chmod 755 myscript.sh
```

and set it aswell to execute in nautilus like on the following example picture:

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the original question was regarding pure command-line logins (not using X graphics at all).

Comment: If you call a script with preceding language, the script doesn't need to be executable. The `.desktop` file doen't need to be executable anyway, only if you use it as a double- click item on the desktop.